# Install Neo4j Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, neo4j

I am following [this blog](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/?_ga=2.249168388.2041192375.1507250087-893468657.1507250087) to install latest Neo4j in Ubuntu 18.04.

I already update ubuntu with following commands.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

When I followed `Neo4j` installation step at the end every time getting the error:

```
Unable to locate package neo4j
```

Problem is here:

```
$ sudo apt-get udpate

Reading package lists... Done                                                                   
E: Release file for https://debian.neo4j.org/repo/stable/Release is not valid yet (invalid for another 1min 22s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
W: Debian shuts down public FTP services currently still used in your sources.list(5) as 'ftp://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/'.
   See press release https://debian.org/News/2017/20170425 for details.
```

Comment: If you can't get around this, there's an option to install from a tarball

Comment: "Release file for https://debian.neo4j.org/repo/stable/Release is not valid yet (invalid for another 1min 22s)." – Looks like you need to try again in 1 minute and 22 seconds.

Comment: Debian shuts down public FTP services, there is an alternative for that.

Answer (score 11):

I also had the same problem.

---

Inorder to install neo4j in ubuntu 18.04

Enter as root

```
$ sudo su
```

Follow these steps

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
$ echo 'deb http://debian.neo4j.org/repo stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/neo4j.list
$ apt update
$ apt install neo4j
```

This will help you..

Comment: This is the right answer, is working for me.

Comment: I'd recommend adding the TLS enabled https://debian.neo4j.org/repo - instead of cleartext HTTP.

Comment: Also get the key with certificate verification. If 
`wget -O - https://debian.neo4j.org/neotechnology.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -` doesn't work without error, something is likely wrong with your TLS certificate store.